# android, disabling the save button for one hour

Tags: android

i am trying to disable the save button for exactly 1 hour, before the user can save data again. I have come up with some code but since i am still really new to programming i am kind of stuck and any help would be appritiated.

The problem is the button does not lock when i click save.

```
public void AddData(){

gumb_poslji.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance();
        Integer cDay = calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Integer cHour = calander.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        Integer cDayOfTheWeek = calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
        Integer cMonth = calander.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;




        int seekBarProgressValue = seekBar.getProgress();
        String strI = String.valueOf(seekBarProgressValue);
        String poslji_data = strI;
        boolean pregled_vnosa = myDb.insertData(poslji_data,cHour,cDay,cDayOfTheWeek,cMonth);
        if (pregled_vnosa==true)
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Vnos uspešen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        else
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Vnos neuspešen!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
gumb_poslji.setEnabled(true);
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3600000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                gumb_poslji.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

}

Comment: please explain where you stuck

Comment: check edit please

Comment: you have to switch `setEnabled(true)` and `setEnabled(false)` current code **disables** the button after `3600000 ms`, However, this might be not the best way to do this, a simple Kill for the app will reset the button to it's original state (enabled)

Answer (score -1):

```
Handler mHandler= new Handler();
static Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        gumb_poslji.setEnabled(false);
        mHandler= .removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }
};

mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3600000);
```